# Image in table-cell issue?

Tags: html, css, html-table

This has really been a pain in my neck. I have 6 images in a table row. Each image, except the first, is smaller than `65px`. The first image, however, is larger than `65px`. When I set the height of the table to `65px`, and set the image to a height of `100%`, the image or table ignores this, and the table is expanded to the height of the logo. How do I fix this issue? I would like to use the `<img>` tag, and not use CSS `background-image` property.

Also, I have noticed that all the images except the first one are aligned vertically in the middle. Why is the first one not like the rest?

I am developing this for mobile.

Here is my table layout:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a><img/></a></td>
        <td><a><img/></a></td>
        <td><a><img/></a></td>
        <td><a><img/></a></td>
        <td><a><img/></a></td>
        <td><a><img/></a></td>
        <td><a><img/></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not sure the problem. This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/XxWMX/) seems to work.  I'm wondering, are you trying to set the `tr` to 65px or the `td`? `tr` won't do anything.

Comment: @Scrimothy that is weird you said that, because just before i posted my question i did that, but i did not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify `height:65px;` on the `<td>` not on the `<table>`

See this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cafw4/2/)**

it should solve your issue.

Comment: Ah, i was adding it to the <table> tag. Why can i not set the height of the table though?

Comment: well I don't know in fact, I just noticed it in previous projects but I must say, I didn't dig into it and I can't say why... please don't poke me with a stick :) This could be an other good question.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 : Set table-spacing=0, table-margin= 0 and then height of td =65px and it will work.

jsfiddle.net/9m4f7/2/

Option2 : set height of image to 65px and width to auto; in table make text-align to center and this will also work.

Comment: Could you give a jsfiddle of Option Number 1?